# How to use a for loop to move a rectangle position in a canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Firstly, I'm new to canvas and I've been trying to wrap my head around this for 2 days so I'd really appreciate any help. My goal is to make the green rectangle animate upwards 1 pixel at a time (the amount doesn't really matter for now) but i'll eventually also want to do the same for the red one. If I annotate out the for loop you can see the rectangles in my desired starting position, however when i add the for loop back in the canvas is blank when in theory I'm hoping for the green rectangle to move upwards. (Or downwards, doesn't actually matter).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height;


  function rectangles() {

    var y = 0;
    // Starting point rectangles
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#006847";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 450);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CE1126";
    ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 200, 450);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.save();
    /*for (i = 0; i < 450; i++) {
        y = y + 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillRect(0, y, 200, 450);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    }*/
  }

  setInterval(rectangles, 2000);
});
```

```css
CSS : #canvas {
  border: 3px #000 solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need of a `for` loop. You can accomplish this using just an `if` statement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        cw = canvas.width,
        ch = canvas.height,
        GY = 0,
        RY = 0;

    rectangles();

    function rectangles() {
        if (GY > -450 && RY > -450) {
            GY -= 1;  // pixel
            RY -= 1;
        } else if (GY == -450 && RY == -450) {
            GY = 450;
            RY = 450;
        }
        // Starting point rectangles
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        // green
        ctx.fillStyle = "#006847";
        ctx.fillRect(0, GY, 200, 450);
        // red
        ctx.fillStyle = "#CE1126";
        ctx.fillRect(400, RY, 200, 450);
        requestAnimationFrame(rectangles);
    }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 3px #000 solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this. @siam

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

The reason is: Your browser will not render anything until your script has finished executing (because only then the browser gets back to its rendering context).

Use `requestAnimationFrame`: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height;

  var y = 0;

  function rectangles() {

    // Starting point rectangles
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#006847";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 450);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CE1126";
    ctx.fillRect(400, 0, 200, 450);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.save();
    y++;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(0, y, 200, 450);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    if (y < 450)
      requestAnimationFrame( rectangles );
  }


  setInterval(rectangles, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited: siam did a far better answer after this: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596485/how-to-use-a-for-loop-to-move-a-rectangle-position-in-a-canvas/42596790#answer-42598764)

The canvas become blank because in function rectangles(), the for loop calculates the position and draws the rectangle in a blink, showing us the final state(which is blank) before we see any animation.

So we have put some time between each time we draw the new rectangle. I also added an index i to record how much time have passed, to calculate the new position of rectangles. Please check the snippet and comment and see if it's desired.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        cw = canvas.width,
        ch = canvas.height;
        step = 1; // Distance the rectangle move each time
        refresh = 10; // Repaint interval
        var i = 0; // Record how far has the rectangle go

    function rectangles() {
        // Starting point rectangles
        ctx.save();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#006847";
        // Leave blank area with height: i*step
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, ch-i*step); 
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#CE1126";
        ctx.fillRect(200, 0, 100, ch-i*step);
        ctx.closePath();

        ctx.save();
        i ++;
        // The canvas is blank, stop drawing
        if (ch-i*step < 0) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
    }
  interval = setInterval(rectangles, refresh);
  });
```

```css
#canvas {
    border: 3px #000 solid;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="225" width="300"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jrying . Exactly what I was hoping for, now I just plan to develop it slightly further to have the animation looping.

Comment: You are welcome. :)
Then maybe you can do something in 
`if (ch-i*step < 0) {clearInterval(interval)}`

Comment: Sorry but your answer is very poor, -1  you may have solved the OPs problem but have just encouraged further bad habits. Don't use `setInterval` (very bad) for animation use `requestAnimationFrame`. Dont save state for no reason and dont call `ctx.save` without a corresponding `ctx.restore`. Don't call `beginPath` or `closePath` if not needed. Please take the time to create a quality answer as this does not help the OP and others at all in the long run.

Comment: @Blindman67 
First, thank you for listing the bad habits. I didn't think much when I first saw this problem and can't resist to do something easy to make it work. And I didn't aware how my words may affect people. I admit it's not the right attitude to pursue or share knowledge. Thank you for point this out, I really appreciate it and will keep it in mind.

Comment: @Blindman67 Fortunatley I'm currently actually working on something that requires me to use the setInterval function with the canvas just to show I can do it, hence this method. However I have looked into requestAnimationFrame and understand that it is more efficient. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you couldn't achieve is because the canvas is single entity. You can't move rectangles until you clear canvas. `clearRect` is here for rescue.

I've created on function called `clearCanvas`. It will run and clear canvas before re-positioning rectangles. So, you are re-drawing canvas in every two seconds with newly calculated positions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    cw = canvas.width,
    ch = canvas.height;

  var x = 100;
  var y = 100;

  function rectangles() {
    clearCanvas();
    var y = 0;
    // Starting point rectangles
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#006847";
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 50, 50);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#CE1126";
    ctx.fillRect(x + 400, 0, 50, 50);
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.save();


    if (x < 10) {
      x = 100;
    }
    x = x - 10;

  }

  setInterval(rectangles, 400);

  function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  }

});
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 3px #000 solid;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-container">
  <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```